# Page Up in copy-mode in tmux

Tags: configuration, tmux

Using `tmux 1.4`, instead of using `<prefix>PPage` to switch to copy mode and be able to navigate in the previous pages, I'd like to be able to use `PPage` / `NPage` in a more "natural way":

- First Page Up switch to copy-mode -u
- Following Page Up move one page up at a time, Page Down will move down, too

Adding `bind-key -n PPage copy-mode -u` does the first, but not the second.

Any idea ? (if useful, I'm using iterm2 on OSX)

Comment: this should be on superuser, if you want to get an answer.